# Regular expression needed for 3 variants that all start the same and must be one of the three

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the following into a js regex:

I need to include the following

- gtm.click
- gtm.linkClick
- gtm.formSubmit

There are other things that start with gtm. so it cannot just be "gtm.*"

I don;t use regular expressions often enough. Any help on this appreciated. I was trying the following without luck:

```
gtm\.*click|gtm.formSubmit
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: `gtm\.(?:click|linkClick|formSubmit)`?

Comment: Thanks @Oriol what does ?: do I have not seen it? I will research it. Thanks

Comment: That's to avoid capturing the group. You can remove it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want those then

```
gtm\.(click|linkClick|formSubmit)
```

Comment: Thanks I'm kicking myself I did know how to do that. Regex just intimidates me. Accepting shortly

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
gtm\.(click|linkClick|formSubmit)
```

Explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/jP1bO4/1)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will match anything which starts with `gtm.` and continues with at least one letter:

`(gtm\.)[a-zA-Z]+`

If you want to match numbers also use:

`(gtm\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+`